# MySQL Sort users by highest total count from counts on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

Similar to stackoverflow, I have a database of `users` who `vote`, `comment`, and make other actions. I am *trying* to return a sorted result of the top 10 users who have made the most actions based on the combined count of all  of the actions a user has made, along with the actual count of total actions said user made.

---

Below is my table structure.

### Users Table

Typical users data such as an incrementing id, username, email, etc.

```
| id | username |
-----------------
| 1  | bob      |
| 2  | jane     |
```

### Votes Table

Has an incrementing id, user_id fk and type of vote made.

```
| id | user_id | type    |
| 1  | 1       | up_vote |
| 2  | 2       | up_vote |
```

### Comments Table

Same as the votes table, typical stuff here.

```
| id | user_id | comment        |
---------------------------------
| 1  | 1       | hello, world   |
| 1  | 1       | goodbye, world |
```

---

### Intended results:

```
results needed
| total_actions | user_id | username |
-------------------------------------|
| 3             | 1       | bob      |
| 1             | 2       | jane     |
```

---

### What I actually know how to do, albeit probably not the most efficient way...

#### Users sorted by most votes, along with the count

```
select `users`.*,
    (
        select count(*)
        from `votes`
        where `users`.`id` = `votes`.`user_id`
    ) as `votes_count` 
from `users` 
order by `votes_count` desc 
limit 10
```

#### Users sorted by most comments, along with the count

```
select `users`.*,
    (
        select count(*)
        from `comments`
        where `users`.`id` = `comments`.`user_id`
    ) as `comments_count` 
from `users` 
order by `comments_count` desc 
limit 10
```

---

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can left join aggregate queries that compute the total votes and comments per user, and sort in the outer query, like so:

```
select 
    coalesce(v.cnt, 0) + coalesce(c.cnt, 0) total_actions, 
    u.id,
    u.username
from users u
left join (select user_id, count(*) cnt from votes group by user_id) v 
    on v.user_id = u.id
left join (select user_id, count(*) cnt from comments group by user_id) c
    on c.user_id = u.id
order by total_actions desc
limit 10
```

Comment: working lovely! had to change user_id to id instead (to match the users table) thanks!

Comment: Welcome @GiovanniS! If fixed `user_id` in the query.

Answer (score 1):

While I prefer GMB's method (using `LEFT JOIN` with each subquery) I'll show here how to combine your existing queries. Just use both correlated subqueries, and add them together to get the total.

```
select `users`.*,
    (
        select count(*)
        from `votes`
        where `users`.`id` = `votes`.`user_id`
    ) +
    (
        select count(*)
        from `comments`
        where `users`.`id` = `comments`.`user_id`
    ) as total_actions
from `users` 
order by total_actions desc 
limit 10
```